# Is that possible to recognize korean with pocketsphinx?

Tags: android, voice-recognition, voice

I'm making app like "SIRI" with working with korean. I already made main activity about recognizing word. But I couldn't find how to make app like OK google.
I mean that when user says "OK GOOGLE", Google voice recognizer is activated.
I really want to implement like this feature. I have googled 24 hours and i found pocketsphinx-android.. It seems to enable this feature. But I visited Official page, there are many language models except Korean.
Is that work for korean? If not, How can i implement this feature??
Sorry for bad English. have a nice day~

Answer (score 1):

I've thought about working on something like this to translate youtube videos for my personal use, and it doesn't seem that straight forward for languages that use non roman characters for someone that is native english speaker.

From their docs, you will need a dictionary, a language model and an acoustic model.

A **naive** way I would go about building the dictionary is to first map hangul character into how it would sound in english (there are websites out there that have this), then find an exhaustive list of korean words, and decompose their characters then map them into the format for .dict file you would need, like so:

'bout B AW T

'cause K AH Z

'course K AO R S

'cuse K Y UW Z

'em AH M

'frisco F R IH S K OW

'frisco F R IH S K OW

For the language model, I would follow this(http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutoriallm) using korean text found mining forums and such, but I would swap out the hangul with the english equivalent.

I would then auto generate a acoustic model using say on osx or espeak.

With this you could test it out with their example here(http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx)

Comment: Thanks! It was very helpful.